# Unsorted lists with an even amount of elements produce an IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, quicksort

I am trying to create a program that implements a quick select algorithm in order to find the median of a list; That median is then used to calculate the difference between each other element in the list to itself.

For example,

> `lst = [1,3,2]
>   sortedList = [1,2,3]`

would return

> lstMedian = 2

the sumDifference then is

> x = 2 - sortedList[0]
>
> y = 2- sortedList[2]
>
> sumDifference = x + y

I have been able to implement this for the most part, sorted lists with both even and odd number of elements work along with all unsorted odd length lists, however, that is not the case for an unsorted even length list.

The traceback using a randomly generated unsorted even-length list is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[26, 66, 43, 47, 73, 75, 52, 81, 21, 73, 32, 92]
  File "~store_location.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
X:  63
  File "~store_location.py", line 96, in main
    y = quickSelect(lst, x)
  File "~store_location.py", line 77, in quickSelect
    return quickSelect(largerList, k - m - count)
  File "~store_location.py", line 77, in quickSelect
    return quickSelect(largerList, k - m - count)
  File "~store_location.py", line 77, in quickSelect
    return quickSelect(largerList, k - m - count)
  File "~store_location.py", line 79, in quickSelect
    return aList[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am using 3 primary functions to calculate this:

sumDistance:

```
def sumDistance(lst, median):
    """
    Find the total distance from each building to the optimal store location
    :param lst: Given list
    :param median: Calculated median of give list
    :return: sum of distances
    """
    total = 0

    for location in range(0, len(lst) - 1):
        total += abs(median - lst[location])

    return total
```

Find median index:

```
def quickSelectHelper(L):
    """
    Find the index of the correct median depending on the length of the list (odd or even)
    :param L: Given list
    :return: the Median the needs to be translated (k'th element)
    """
    if len(L) % 2 == 0 and len(L) >= 2:
        idx1 = int((0.5 * len(L)) - 1)
        idx2 = (len(L) // 2)
        calculatedMedian = (L[idx1] + L[idx2]) // 2
    elif len(L) % 2 != 0 and len(L) >= 1:
        calculatedMedian = (0.5 * len(L)) - 0.5

    return calculatedMedian
```

Find median value:

```
def quickSelect(aList, k):
    """
    Sort the list until the k'th element is found
    :param aList: given list
    :param k: the element to find (k'th)
    :return: The median value of the given list
    """
    # print("qS at it again: ", aList, "with a length of: ", len(aList))
    if len(aList) != 0:
        pivot = aList[len(aList) // 2]
        smallerList = []
        largerList = []
        count = 0

        for dist in range(len(aList)):
            if aList[dist] > pivot:
                largerList.append(aList[dist])
            elif aList[dist] < pivot:
                smallerList.append(aList[dist])
            else:
                count += 1

        m = len(smallerList)

        if m <= k < m + count:
            return pivot
        elif m > k:
            return quickSelect(smallerList, k)
        else:
            return quickSelect(largerList, k - m - count)

    return aList[0]
```

If my context is lacking feel free to look at the [entirety of my code](https://pastebin.com/r8tnT96e) (~100 lines)

Comment: `aList` is occasoinally an empty list - when you attempt to return `aList[0]`, you generate an IndexError, as `aList[0]` doesn't exist in an empty list.

Comment: `if aList[dist] > pivot` - if `pivot` happens to be the largest number in the list, `largerList` will remain empty. Did you perhaps mean `if aList[dist] >= pivot` ?

Answer (score 0):

The return for your recursive base case is incorrect. When `quickSelect` is called with `aList=[]`, you `return aList[0]`, even though `aList` is empty (and `[][0]` is always an IndexError). Not sure what makes sense as your base case (`None`?), but you may also have to handle it in whatever calls `quickSelect`.

Comment: @NateMendes Well, did this answer your question? Don’t forget to [upvote/accept answers to your questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/158402) `:)`